# Understanding how child elements inherit parent css properties

Tags: html, css

I have a lack of understanding how the css settings of a parent restrict its children.

Simple example:

I have a `container` with three buttons.

- play button
- fast forward button
- fast backwards button

My **goal** is the following:

- create a grid 1x3 (row x column)
- aling buttons inside of the grid

With this I went to work and ended up here:

```css
.adaptations {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.video-button-container {
    height: 100px;
    width: auto;
    
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 33% 33% 33%;    
}
.video-button {
    height: 100%;
}

.video-button img {
    height: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="adaptations video-button-container">
    <button type="button" class="video-button">
        <img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/552/785/png-clipart-smile-mouth-love-white.png">
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="video-button middle-button">
        <img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/552/785/png-clipart-smile-mouth-love-white.png">
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="video-button">
        <img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/552/785/png-clipart-smile-mouth-love-white.png">
    </button>
</div>
```

Here's my **problem**: I managed to implement the said goal with *fixed* sizes (width, height). However, it is not desireable since screen sizes differ, hence, make it responsive and here lies my problem.

What I learned is that if I set my parent-div to `height: 100px;` the child elements will adjust themselves inside that div. Therefore I said `height: 100%`. Which sounds like (as far as I understand this): "You can use all the height that is available to you, therefore max. 100px)

Can you enlighten me on what I am missing?

Comment: it's not perfectly clear what's the exact struggle you are having. Anyway if you want to make sense of the html you shared, just use `max-width: 100%;` on your `.video-button img` css rule

Comment: @Beru try changing your `.video-button { height: 100%; }` to `.video-button { height: inherit; }` and let us know if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you are trying to achieve.

```css
.adaptations {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.video-button-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 33% 33% 33%;
}

.video-button {
  height: inherit; /* Use 'inherit' here instead of '100%' */
}

.video-button img {
  height: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="adaptations video-button-container">
  <button type="button" class="video-button">
    <img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/552/785/png-clipart-smile-mouth-love-white.png">
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="video-button middle-button">
    <img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/552/785/png-clipart-smile-mouth-love-white.png">
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="video-button">
    <img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/552/785/png-clipart-smile-mouth-love-white.png">
  </button>
</div>
```